# Is there a bug in my custom tree implementation for finding shortest path to leaf node?

Tags: python, tree

I'm trying to implement a custom tree, for a problem that takes the input as the number of nodes and the edges/connections between each node and gives the output as the length of the shortest path to the leaf node from the root.

For the smaller test cases, I've tried it gave correct output but for some reason, it gives runtime error on hackerank for all the other cases, is there a bug? I tried to find it but I coudnt

**Code:**

```
 
class tree:
    class Node:
 
        def __init__(self,parent,children=[]):

            self.Parent=parent # p capital
            self.children=children



    def __init__(self,n,connections=[]):

        self.root = self.Node(None,[])
        self.n = n # tree.n
        self.connections = connections # list of all edges
        self.Positions = {}   # initializing all positions in dictionary , for all nodes
        self.Positions[1]=self.root # 1 is always root
        if self.n>1:
            for i in range(2,n+1):
                self.Positions[i]=self.Node(None,[])

    def joinNode(self,parent,node): # number of the two nodes , like 1-3 etc..
        self.Positions[parent].children.append(self.Positions[node])
        self.Positions[node].Parent=self.Positions[parent]

    def joinAll(self):
        for p,n in self.connections:
            self.joinNode(p,n)

    def Depth(self,p):
        """Return the number of levels separating Position p from the root."""
        if p==self.root:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + self.Depth(p.Parent)

    def minDepth(self):
        return min(self.Depth(self.Positions[p]) for p in self.leafnodes())
    
    def leafnodes(self):
        return list(set(x[0] for x in self.connections)^set(i for i in range(1,n+1)))


if __name__=='__main__':
    n=int(input())
    if n==1:
        print(0)
    else:
        connections=[]
        for i in range(1,n):
            array=input()
            edge=list(map(int,array.split()))
            connections.append(edge)

        mytree=tree(n,connections)
        mytree.joinAll()
        print(mytree.minDepth())
        print(mytree.connections)
```

**Sample input**

```
5
1 4
4 2
2 3
3 5
```

**sample output**

```
4
```

Comment: Could you please provide your test case and your expected output? so that it can help us to make sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Gcode i have edited my question to include the sample testcase

Comment: Thanks for your updating. Could you provide a test case which you got a wrong output? or the number of minDepth should be 5 and you got 4?

Comment: the test cases were hidden, and its given that number of nodes <= 10^6

Comment: I guess for deep trees you could run into a stack overflow error. What is the error message? Anyway, try to make your Depth method non-recursive. Just a loop.